# Can AJAX create a Timeout when the request is back in time, but the JS thread is busy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible for an ajax request to return a timeout, because the JavaScript thread is unavailable?

Say I send a request, after which the backend returns a success code ~500 ms later. Immediately after sending the request, I perform a really expensive function (using practically all CPU for 10 seconds), will my request end up as en error due to the timeout, or as a success because it was the function returned after 500ms?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my/url",
    error: function(){
       //do something
    },
    success: function(){
       //do something
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
expensiveFunction(); //takes 10 seconds
```

Comment: i think you need to use promises here

Comment: @YogeshMistry will promises behave differently with regard to timeouts?

Comment: @DaniëlCamps the success will be invoked after ~500ms, which means ajax is done. No timeout will happen anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try it? It's the best way to find these things out.

**Note - running the below snippet will probably lock up your browser for about 5 seconds.**

```js
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',startAjaxRequest);
function startAjaxRequest() {
  var errorTimer;

  function asyncFunction(callback) {
      errorTimer = setTimeout(fail, 2000);
      document.getElementById('FakeServerResponse').addEventListener('click',callback);
  }

  function fail() {
    console.log("Error!");
  }

  function cpuHog() {
      var startTime = new Date().getTime();
      var i = 0;
      while(startTime > new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 5)) {
        i++;
      }
      console.log("Cpu Hogging process is done");
      return i;
  }

  asyncFunction(function() {
    clearTimeout(errorTimer);
    console.log("Async process is complete");
  });
  setTimeout(cpuHog,0);
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start!</button>
<button id="FakeServerResponse">Click to fake the Server Responding</button>
```

Try clicking start then immediately clicking the "Click to fake the Server Responding" button. You'll see the console says the process is complete.

Then try clicking start and not faking the server response. You'll see the error callback is hit.

This is because when new events (literal events triggering, or timeouts firing) occur in javascript, they are added to a "message queue" which is evaluated one by one when javascript has time. When the server responds to your request, an event is fired inside jquery (readystatechange) which is added to that message queue. Similarly, your timeout (of 2000ms in the example I have created) is just placed in a setTimeout inside jquery. When the timeout is up, an event is added to the message queue to evaluate that timeout. So long as this event is added after the server responded, the server response will be evaluated first. If the timeout gets hit before the server responded, then the error will occur first.

Comment: I don't know why I was so surprised that my browser froze for a few seconds running this code.

Comment: This does not prove that ajax timeouts after invoking heavy function in the success handler.

Comment: @George - You raise a good point actually, I'll pop a warning on there in case people didn't see the context and run it unaware.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek - I'm not sure I get what you're saying - that it doesn't prove the particular example works? It doesn't show the jquery ajax function, no, but it does show an example of an asynchronous function waiting for the event loop to have a free spot before running it's callback, which is the core of the question, no?

Comment: @Hecksa so you're saying Ajax can say 'timeout', even though the server responds quickly, simply because JavaScript is busy?

Comment: @DaniëlCamps That's what I tried to mention. Busy javascript has nothing to do with ajax timeout, so although it's a nice answer, it does not answer your question.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't understand what you were trying to get at there, @NielsSteenbeek. I'm with you now - yes, I've slightly missed the mark here. I'll try to update the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek you raised a good point, but based on your edit I think you may have misinterpreted my question. I'm not calling a heavy function in the succes handler, I'm calling a heavy function after sending an asynchronous Ajax call. Whether or not the succes handler is heavy doesn't matter at all, is could simply be an `alert("Hello");` and the question would remain the same

Comment: I've updated the answer. I have an explanation that I'm about to edit in, the short story is that I'm pretty sure the success function gets hit.

Comment: @Hecksa that's quite the contraption you built there :) The thing is - obviously my real life application is much more complex than this one, but I have very strong evidence suggesting that a request which normally takes 400 ms to finish, causes an Ajax timeout on a page which take an extremely long time to load (the timeout is set at 15 seconds, but the rendering time surpasses this even). Therefore, I am still not 100% convinced that this answer perfectly mimics an Ajax call. If I can find the time I will add your hogger function to my live setting and try it with an actual Ajax call -thanks

Comment: @DaniëlCamps - It should be basically equivalent to the jquery implementation - I did take a look at the jquery source to check how it was handled there. I think it might be a good idea to try stripping your live example down to the bare bones and see if you can get it working, because I can't see a reason it shouldn't without some weird circumstances causing it to fail.

Comment: @Hecksa I promise that I will do that as soon as I have to time. I will mention you to let you know